# Replace a specific value from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have the following array in PHP

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Test
            [year] => 2015
        )

)
```

I get these valus from MySQL database. Now I want to update the value of `name` only in `values_1` array. Is there any simple way I can do it in PHP?

Comment: Seems more like a json string rather than an actual array

Comment: I actually pasted the wrong code, I'll edit my question right now.

Comment: You need at most 3 minutes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your array is called 'arrayVariable':

```
$arrayVariable[0]["name"] = 'New string';
```

For further information about php arrays please refer to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) link [Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) posted in a comment below your question.

[Array accessing section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)
of this documentation describes how to access array elements using square bracket syntax.

[Array modifying section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) describes how to modify value in an array.

I also encourage you to read [do's and don'ts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts) section to avoid making common array related mistakes.